# Is it safe to use a 2 Amp capacity voltage stabilizer with a refrigerator compressor LRA of 8.1 Amp?

Tags: voltage

Background:

Recently, one of my refrigerator got damaged due to frequent voltage fluctuations, despite having in-built voltage stabilizer claimed to be installed by the manufacturer. So, I intend to use another refrigerator (LG Fresh Master) having 170 (or so) liter capacity with an external voltage stabilizer. This LG refrigerator has not been used for almost one decade. So, technical specification affixed behind its body is not readable. I do not have its papers handy so as to know the model number. Despite extensive web search, I have failed to guess model number and find technical specification. However, I have found following details printed on its compressor.

**LRA:8.1**

**230V~50Hz~RLA:0.8**

I think -

• LRA denotes Locked Rotor Amps, the maximum current spike during a motor start.

• RLA points to Rated Load Amps, the current that a compressor draws while operating (not startup).

I have shortlisted following voltage stabilizer based on my little understanding.

• Voltage Stabilizer: V-Guard VGSD 50

**• Capacity: 2 Ampere**

• Working range (input): 130 VAC-290 VAC

• Use suggested by manufacturer: One refrigerator up to 300 litre

• Time delay: 3 Minutes ± 20 Seconds ITDS

**Question:
Since LRA of installed compressor is 8.1 Ampere, whether shortlisted voltage stabilizer will work perfectly, as its capacity is only 2 Ampere.**

Answer (score 3):

No.

You expect a device to work at a factor of 4 times its rating?

Do not do this, but get a voltage stabilzer with sufficient capacity.

Answer (score 2):

Consult with the factory.

A large startup surge is characteristic of ... almost every motor load, ever.  Since the unit is marketed for refrigerators, and a 2A LRA refrigerator would be a small one indeed, possibly too tiny to even work... they surely must have an answer for startup surge.

Surge suppressors are never bad, but you also need something that will disconnect the load when voltage ranges beyond its specification.  Low voltage is hard on fridges too.